# How to troubleshoot Windows? Post your checklist

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, debug, diagnostic

There is sometimes a situation when Windows suddenly goes crazy: is slow, unresponsive, some things don't work, it crashes. I wonder how do you approach diagnosing those issues.

I'm merely a programmer, not really knowing Windows too deply. There is probably more people like me... I strongly believe that experienced Windows administrators have a bunch of useful tricks that can make diagnosing easier.

Please post your techniques, the more advanced/tricky/unstandard, the better.

Answer (score 9):

Let me start with the list:

**General:**

- Install most current updates/service packs.
- Verify drivers, look for conflicts, upgrade to newer ones.
- Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see a bit more details about what's being run
- Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)(combined filemon and regmon) to see details about particular process
- Check the services - (services.msc from command prompt).
- Problems with graphics/sound (especially with older apps) - verify DirectX (run dxdiag from console), try disabling hardware acceleration.
- See what's being run on windows boot time - [Windows start points](http://antivirus.about.com/od/windowsbasics/tp/autostartkeys.htm)
- Scan for viruses (anyways, you should have it updated and running all the time).
- Run some [anti-malware tool](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)
- Look at windows event log (eventvwr from console)
- Make sure there is at least ~250mb free space on Windows drive.
- Check virtual memory settings.

**Network:**

- See network settings (from console: ncpa.cpl and ipconfig /all)
- Inspect firewall configuration. If you have turned Windows firewall off, check if it isn't started up.
- Look if hosts file is not modified %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

**Hardware:**

- Run full HDD scan and defragment.
- Run memory test http://www.memtest86.com/

You should know most (if not all) of it already, but hopefully this helps somebody.

Comment: Be careful with the order of Apply Updates and Check Firewall - I've been bitten when a service pack re-enabled it.

Answer (score 2):

Start -> Run -> msconfig -> startup tab

Uncheck everything.  Restart and try to duplicate the problem (some apps/services will not function).  If the problem is resolved, go back into msconfig and re-check half the startup items.  Restart & duplicate the problem.  Narrow the services down by 1/2 each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the a wondrous situation where you have an image of a workstation you can just nuke it, if it was a software problem its fixed, if its a hardware problem you now know.

Comment: On my test machines, "Apply Snapshot" is a god-send.